# Type mismatch error in VBA in populating an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I 'm defining an array like this and populating it directly without using any loops

But its throwing error  "Type mismatch error"

```
Dim battarray() As Integer
x = Sheets("Names").Range("a4")
ReDim battarray(x) As Integer
battarray() = Array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)
```

Can some one help me fix this

Comment: What's in `Sheets("Names").Range("a4")`?

Comment: Remove `As Integer` and try again. `Array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)` creates an array of variant, which cant be assigned to an array of integers.

Comment: @bernieIn `Sheets("Names").Range("a4")` is an integer which gives  dynamic size to the array, based on that  `Array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)` also changes

Comment: Try this `x = Val(Trim(Sheets("Names").Range("a4").Value))`

Comment: @shahkalpesh I have tried "Remove As Integer" its still showing the same error

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried `x = Val(Trim(Sheets("Names").Range("a4").Value))` it is still showing the same error

Comment: What line is throwing 'Type Mismatch'? Also, did you remove `As Integer` from line 1 and line 3 in the sample code you posted?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Hey its working I removed `As Integer` from both the lines. Great help thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Remove both instances of `As Integer`, and (optionally) replace them by `As Variant`.

`Array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)` creates an array of type Variant. This cannot be assigned to an array of type `Integer`.

Note that if you're going to hard-code the contents of `battarray`, there's no point `ReDim`ming the array beforehand. This is sufficient:

```
Dim battarray() As Variant
battarray() = Array(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50)
```